# How to enlarge text font size inside a plot?

Tags: plotting

Consider the code below:

```
t1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}];
t2 = Graphics[Text["(a)", {0.2, 0.9}]];
Show[t1, t2]
```

The figure generated is

[image]

The problem is that the label "(a)" is too small. **How to make it bigger?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use Style for this:

```
t1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}];
t2 = Graphics[Text[Style["(a)", 24], {0.2, 0.9}]];
Show[t1, t2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Epilog` too, which will certainly concise everything.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}, Epilog -> {Inset[Style["(a)", FontSize->25], Scaled[{0.1, 0.8}]]}]
```

Just for beautification,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> 600, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.03}], 
 Epilog -> {Inset[Style["(a)", FontSize -> 55], Scaled[{0.1, 0.8}]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.007]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]]
```

[image]